# Gnuplot maximum of an sm b smoothed curve

Tags: gnuplot, smoothing

I have a data file:

```
0.4 -0.97
0.41 -0.96
0.42 -0.95
0.43 -0.93
0.44 -0.92
0.45 -0.91
0.46 -0.90
0.47 -0.88
0.48 -0.87
0.49 -0.86
0.5 -0.84
0.51 -0.83
0.52 -0.82
0.53 -0.81
0.54 -0.80
0.55 -0.78
0.56 -0.77
0.57 -0.76
0.58 -0.74
0.59 -0.73
0.6 -0.72
0.61 -0.71
0.62 -0.70
0.63 -0.69
0.64 -0.67
0.65 -0.66
0.66 -0.65
0.67 -0.64
0.68 -0.62
0.69 -0.61
0.7 -0.60
0.71 -0.59
0.72 -0.58
0.73 -0.56
0.74 -0.55
0.75 -0.54
0.76 -0.53
0.77 -0.52
0.78 -0.51
0.79 -0.50
0.8 -0.49
0.81 -0.47
0.82 -0.47
0.83 -0.46
0.84 -0.44
0.85 -0.43
0.86 -0.42
0.87 -0.41
0.88 -0.40
0.89 -0.39
0.9 -0.38
0.91 -0.49
0.92 -0.48
0.93 -0.47
0.94 -0.46
0.95 -0.44
0.96 -0.43
0.97 -0.42
0.98 -0.41
0.99 -0.40
1.0 -0.39
1.01 -0.38
1.02 -0.37
1.03 -0.36
1.04 -0.35
1.05 -0.34
1.06 -0.33
1.07 -0.32
1.08 -0.31
1.09 -0.30
1.1 -0.30
1.11 -0.29
1.12 -0.28
1.13 -0.27
1.14 -0.26
1.15 -0.25
1.16 -0.24
1.17 -0.24
1.18 -0.23
1.19 -0.22
1.2 -0.21
1.21 -0.20
1.22 -0.20
1.23 -0.19
1.24 -0.18
1.25 -0.17
1.26 -0.17
1.27 -0.16
1.28 -0.15
1.29 -0.14
1.3 -0.13
1.31 -0.12
1.32 -0.11
1.33 -0.11
1.34 -0.10
1.35 -0.09
1.36 -0.08
1.37 -0.08
1.38 -0.07
1.39 -0.06
1.4 -0.05
1.41 -0.04
1.42 -0.03
1.43 -0.03
1.44 -0.02
1.45 -0.01
1.46 -0.01
1.47 -0.00
1.48 0.00
1.49 0.01
1.5 0.02
1.51 0.03
1.52 0.04
1.53 0.04
1.54 0.05
1.55 0.06
1.56 0.06
1.57 0.07
1.58 0.08
1.59 0.08
1.6 0.09
1.61 0.09
1.62 0.10
1.63 0.10
1.64 0.10
1.65 0.11
1.66 0.11
1.67 0.12
1.68 0.12
1.69 0.13
1.7 0.14
1.71 0.14
1.72 0.14
1.73 0.15
1.74 0.15
1.75 0.16
1.76 0.16
1.77 0.17
1.78 0.17
1.79 0.18
1.8 0.19
1.81 0.20
1.82 0.20
1.83 0.21
1.84 0.21
1.85 0.22
1.86 0.22
1.87 0.23
1.88 0.24
1.89 0.24
1.9 0.25
1.91 0.25
1.92 0.26
1.93 0.26
1.94 0.26
1.95 0.27
1.96 0.28
1.97 0.28
1.98 0.28
1.99 0.29
2.0 0.29
2.01 0.29
2.02 0.29
2.03 0.30
2.04 0.30
2.05 0.30
2.06 0.31
2.07 0.32
2.08 0.32
2.09 0.33
2.1 0.33
2.11 0.33
2.12 0.34
2.13 0.34
2.14 0.34
2.15 0.35
2.16 0.35
2.17 0.36
2.18 0.36
2.19 0.36
2.2 0.37
2.21 0.37
2.22 0.37
2.23 0.38
2.24 0.38
2.25 0.38
2.26 0.38
2.27 0.39
2.28 0.39
2.29 0.39
2.3 0.40
2.31 0.40
2.32 0.40
2.33 0.40
2.34 0.41
2.35 0.41
2.36 0.42
2.37 0.42
2.38 0.43
2.39 0.43
2.4 0.43
2.41 0.43
2.42 0.44
2.43 0.44
2.44 0.44
2.45 0.44
2.46 0.45
2.47 0.45
2.48 0.45
2.49 0.45
2.5 0.46
2.51 0.46
2.52 0.46
2.53 0.47
2.54 0.47
2.55 0.47
2.56 0.48
2.57 0.48
2.58 0.49
2.59 0.36
2.6 0.36
2.61 0.36
2.62 0.36
2.63 0.37
2.64 0.37
2.65 0.37
2.66 0.37
2.67 0.38
2.68 0.38
2.69 0.38
2.7 0.38
2.71 0.38
2.72 0.38
2.73 0.38
2.74 0.38
2.75 0.38
2.76 0.38
2.77 0.38
2.78 0.38
2.79 0.39
2.8 0.39
2.81 0.39
2.82 0.39
2.83 0.39
2.84 0.39
2.85 0.28
2.86 0.28
2.87 0.28
2.88 0.28
2.89 0.28
2.9 0.28
2.91 0.28
2.92 0.28
2.93 0.29
2.94 0.29
2.95 0.29
2.96 0.29
2.97 0.29
2.98 0.29
2.99 0.29
3.0 0.19
3.01 0.19
3.02 0.19
3.03 0.19
3.04 0.19
3.05 0.19
3.06 0.19
3.07 0.19
3.08 0.20
3.09 0.20
3.1 0.20
3.11 0.20
3.12 0.20
3.13 0.20
3.14 0.20
3.15 0.20
3.16 0.20
3.17 0.20
3.18 0.21
3.19 0.21
3.2 0.21
3.21 0.21
3.22 0.21
3.23 0.21
3.24 0.21
3.25 0.21
3.26 0.21
3.27 0.21
3.28 0.21
3.29 0.21
3.3 0.21
3.31 0.21
3.32 0.21
3.33 0.21
3.34 0.21
3.35 0.21
3.36 0.21
3.37 0.22
3.38 0.22
3.39 0.22
3.4 0.22
3.41 0.22
3.42 0.22
3.43 0.22
3.44 0.22
3.45 0.22
3.46 0.22
3.47 0.22
3.48 0.22
3.49 0.22
3.5 0.22
3.51 0.23
3.52 0.23
3.53 0.23
3.54 0.23
3.55 0.23
3.56 0.13
3.57 0.13
3.58 0.13
3.59 0.13
3.6 0.13
3.61 0.13
3.62 0.13
3.63 0.13
3.64 0.13
3.65 0.13
3.66 0.13
3.67 0.13
3.68 0.13
3.69 0.13
3.7 0.13
3.71 0.13
3.72 0.14
3.73 0.14
3.74 0.14
3.75 0.14
3.76 0.05
3.77 0.05
3.78 0.05
3.79 0.05
3.8 0.05
3.81 -0.04
3.82 -0.04
3.83 -0.04
3.84 -0.04
3.85 -0.04
3.86 -0.04
3.87 -0.04
3.88 -0.04
3.89 -0.04
3.9 -0.04
3.91 -0.04
3.92 -0.04
3.93 -0.04
3.94 -0.04
3.95 -0.12
3.96 -0.12
3.97 -0.12
3.98 -0.12
3.99 -0.12
4.0 -0.12
4.01 -0.12
4.02 -0.12
4.03 -0.12
4.04 -0.12
4.05 -0.19
4.06 -0.19
4.07 -0.19
4.08 -0.19
4.09 -0.19
4.1 -0.19
4.11 -0.19
4.12 -0.41
4.13 -0.41
4.14 -0.41
4.15 -0.47
4.16 -0.47
4.17 -0.47
4.18 -0.47
4.19 -0.47
4.2 -0.47
4.21 -0.47
4.22 -0.54
4.23 -0.54
4.24 -0.60
4.25 -0.65
4.26 -0.65
4.27 -0.65
4.28 -0.65
4.29 -0.65
4.3 -0.65
4.31 -0.65
4.32 -0.65
4.33 -0.65
4.34 -0.65
4.35 -0.65
4.36 -0.65
4.37 -0.65
4.38 -0.71
4.39 -0.71
4.4 -0.71
4.41 -0.71
4.42 -0.71
4.43 -0.71
4.44 -0.71
4.45 -0.71
4.46 -0.71
4.47 -0.71
4.48 -0.71
4.49 -0.71
4.5 -0.71
4.51 -0.71
4.52 -0.71
4.53 -0.76
4.54 -0.76
4.55 -0.82
4.56 -0.82
4.57 -0.87
4.58 -0.87
4.59 -0.87
4.6 -0.87
4.61 -0.92
4.62 -0.97
4.63 -1.06
4.64 -1.06
4.65 -1.06
4.66 -1.06
4.67 -1.06
4.68 -1.06
4.69 -1.06
4.7 -1.06
4.71 -1.06
4.72 -1.06
4.73 -1.06
4.74 -1.11
4.75 -1.11
4.76 -1.11
4.77 -1.11
4.78 -1.11
4.79 -1.11
4.8 -1.11
4.81 -1.11
4.82 -1.11
4.83 -1.11
4.84 -1.11
4.85 -1.15
4.86 -1.15
4.87 -1.15
4.88 -1.15
```

I wish to create a "well" smoother curve, so i use

```
plot "for_gnuplot" lw 3 w l sm b title ""
```

I get the following image:

[image]

This is very nice, but i wish to mark the maximum in some way. I know that with `sm b` the maximum is not the real maximum of the plot, but i dont know how to mark this new maximum value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the (x,y) data of the smoothed plot to a temporary file, do some statistics on this file, and plot the results:

```
# Generate the data for the smooth plot
set samples 1000
set table "temp.dat"
plot "for_gnuplot" lw 3 w l sm b title "1"
unset table

# Get maximum values and indices of maximum values:
# A_max_y, A_index_max_y, B_max_y, B_index_max_y
stats "for_gnuplot" prefix "A"
stats "temp.dat" using 1:2 prefix "B"

# Calculate positions from indices.
# We need the x-value (first column) at B_index_max_y. We know that the first
# column of "temp.dat" consists of equidistant x-values. So we just fit a
# linear function to map from index to position. (Could be done analytically.)
pos_from_index(x) = a*x + b

fit pos_from_index(x) "for_gnuplot" using 0:1 via a, b
A_xvalue_max_y = pos_from_index(A_index_max_y)

fit pos_from_index(x) "temp.dat" using 0:1 via a, b
B_xvalue_max_y = pos_from_index(B_index_max_y)

# Make some arrows to indicate maximal values
set arrow 1 from A_xvalue_max_y, graph 0.99 to A_xvalue_max_y, A_max_y fill lw 2
set arrow 2 from B_xvalue_max_y, graph 0.8  to B_xvalue_max_y, B_max_y fill lw 2
set label 1 at A_xvalue_max_y, graph 0.99 "max raw" offset 0.2, -0.3
set label 2 at B_xvalue_max_y, graph 0.8  "max smooth" center offset 0, -0.4

# Finally plot the graphs
set terminal png
set output "graph.png"
plot "for_gnuplot" lw 2 w l title "raw" ,\
     "for_gnuplot" lw 2 w l sm b title "smooth"
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

PS: I would be interested if there is a more direct way to access a value from a file at a specific index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link: http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/gnuplot/html/statistics.html

Scroll to "Determining the position of the minimum and maximum".

Comment: As i mentioned i know how to find the real maximum, i would like to find the maximum of the smoother curve. (They are not the same)